# Multiple $_POST on same page PHP

Tags: php

I have a question.

Currently this form will be dynamically generated.

Example,

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="location" id="location1" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit!" />

<input type="text" name="location" id="location2" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit!" />

<input type="text" name="location" id="location3" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit!" />

<input type="text" name="location" id="location4" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
```

So whenever i press submit, it will take last value of form only. How do i make it take all $_POST?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give each input its own name or use:

```
<input type="text" name="location[]" id="location1" />
```

Then PHP will treat it like an array.

Comment: Ah, sometime the simple thing you could forget after facing coding for few hours.

Answer (score 8):

You could give each field a unique name: `location1`, `location2`....

Alternatively, you could build an array.

To do that, add a `[]` to each element's name:

```
<input type="text" name="location[]" id="location1" />
```

this will give you an array in `$_POST["location"]`.

Don't forget that before using the data (e.g. in a database query or page output) you will need to sanitize **each** array element separately (using `mysql_real_escape_string()` or `htmlspecialchars()` or whatever is needed in your situation.)

Answer (score 2):

Either give each input a different name attribute, for example location1, location2, location3 and location4 then access with `$_POST['location1']` `$_POST['location2']` etc.

Alternatively (and probably preferred if this form is being generated 'dynamically'), change the name attribute for each input to location[] then access the values entered as an array in PHP. For example...

**HTML**

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="location[]" id="location1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!" />

    <input type="text" name="location[]" id="location2" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!" />

    <input type="text" name="location[]" id="location3" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!" />

    <input type="text" name="location[]" id="location4" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
print_r($_POST['location']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<form method='post'>";
for($x=1;$x<=4;$x++)
{
echo "<input type='text' name='location".$x."' id='location".$x."'/>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit!' />";
}
echo "</form>";
```